# Появляется ошибка во время npm i

Tags: npm

Появляется ошибка при выполнении npm i. Перед этим выполнил  git clone https://github.com/bem/project-stub.git --depth 1 моя_папка
Git bash запущен от администратора.
лог:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Этот проект не предназначен для запуска в WIndows.

Comment: https://ru.bem.info/technologies/classic/project-stub/#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-project-stub здесб указано, что нужно выполнять команды в git bash из под windows. Информация не актуальна?

Comment: В [issues](https://github.com/bem/project-stub/issues/110) пишут, что windows не поддерживается совсем

Comment: Спасибо, не догадался туда заглянуть.